# Execute command from node js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I use the following code to excute command from node application and this is working...The problem is when there is error I dont get it,I try to debug the code and I when I put break-point in the if(error) It doesnt stops ,any idea why?

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'npm install winston --save';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: try using return command.

Comment: try console.error instead of console.log - that worked for me

Comment: I tried your code and attempted to intentionally trigger an error by changing the `cmd` variable to `np install winston --save`, but I got the error printed out. How are you placing the breakpoint?

Comment: @pbwned - I try it but it doesnt work for me...

Comment: @yjwong- what do you mean by NP ?can you provide example what I should change?

Comment: he probably meant NPM

Comment: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn  

According to this source, where the author tries a different method, you should try to change your exec part to the one on the following:

`exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
}); `

Comment: @pbwned - please provide it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/)
According to this source, where the author tries a different method, you should try to change your exec part to the one on the following:

```
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```